# How to combine first element of one array with first element of second array and second with second and so on

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having two arrays,

the first array contains:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

and the second one contains:

```
100, 200, 300, 400, 500
```

the result should be:

```
[ [ '1', '100' ],
  [ '2', '200' ],
  [ '3', '300' ],
  [ '4', '400' ],
  [ '5', '500' ] ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) through the array assuming they are the same size. [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) will give you the strings you want.

```js
const first = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const second = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
var result= [];

for(var i=0; i<first.length; i++){
  result.push([first[i].toString(), second[i].toString()]);
}

console.log(result);
```

If arrays are not the same size and you only want while values exist in both indexes you could check for null or undefined.

```js
const first = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 600, 700, 800]
const second = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700]
var result= [];

for(var i=0; i<first.length; i++){
  if(first[i] && second[i]){
    result.push([first[i].toString(), second[i].toString()]);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I get undefined in the last row of the output, do you know what is the problem?

Comment: Are you using <= or < in your for loop?  Are the arrays the same size?

Comment: I am using < in my loop. Not all of the arrays are the same size.

Comment: If they are not the same size, you'd get undefined.  You could check for undefined or null and replace with a default value. Your example provided same size arrays. What would you expect output to be when they are different?

Comment: For example input is: 
Z 
a, b, c
And the expected output should be [ [ 'Z', 'a' ] ], but I am getting 
[ [ 'Z', 'a' ] ]
undefined

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your criteria, see if that makes sense?

Comment: I understand now, I get the logic, but it is still printing undefined.

Comment: Can you share the code that makes it reproducible?

Comment: I've updated my question, you can see the code.

Comment: When I converted your code to strings it works.  Is Z defined elewhere? Check the edits queue for your question and youll see the working example.

Comment: Mhm, can the problem be if we enter the input elements by terminal(stdin)?

Comment: yes, I'd need to see complete example to understand the issue. Hope I was able to provide some learning experiences here!

Comment: I understand it, but u can see the full code in my question update because it's still returning undefined

Answer (score 0):

Simply With [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const b = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
const c = [];
a.forEach((el, ind) => {
  c.push([el+"", b[ind]+""])
});
console.log(c)
```

Or with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const b = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
const c = a.reduce((acc, curr, ind) => {
  acc.push([curr+"", b[ind]+""]);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(c)
```

*Tip: `+""` is like doing `.toString()` will convert `number` into `text`*

Comment: Looks like results should be converted to strings